# Split dataframe into groups of X number of rows and constraint on number of types in a group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe 'DF' that contains columns 'COLUMN_Y' and 'Category'. I want to split the dataframe into chunks of SIZE, X.  However, there is a constraint that there can be no more than 3 Categories in each group fo size X.

The idea is to return a list for a DF that contains a split-DF of size X (with the above constraint)  and everything else left in the DF that could not meet these criteria are in a 'left-over'/'remainder-DF.

I can split a DF to get a chunk of size X , but have no idea where to go putting the constraint of no more than 3 Categories , other than looping over all permutations until I get what a match.

Any logic and advice would be helpful.

Thanks,

What I have :

```
============================================================================
|            COLUMN_Y               ||||          CATEGORY                 |
============================================================================
|            value1                 ||||           CAT1                    |
|            value2                 ||||           CAT1                    |
|            value3                 ||||           CAT1                    |
|            value4                 ||||           CAT1                    |
|            value5                 ||||           CAT1                    |
|            value6                 ||||           CAT2                    |
|            value7                 ||||           CAT2                    |
|            value8                 ||||           CAT2                    |
|            value9                 ||||           CAT2                    |
|            value10                ||||           CAT2                    |
|            value11                ||||           CAT3                    |
|            value12                ||||           CAT3                    |
|            value13                ||||           CAT4                    |
============================================================================
```

What I want if SIZE==5:

```
DFs[0]
============================================================================
|            COLUMN_Y               ||||          CATEGORY                 |
============================================================================
|            value1                 ||||           CAT1                    |
|            value2                 ||||           CAT1                    |
|            value3                 ||||           CAT1                    |
|            value4                 ||||           CAT1                    |
|            value5                 ||||           CAT1                    |
============================================================================
DFs[1]
============================================================================
|            COLUMN_Y               ||||          CATEGORY                 |
============================================================================
|            value6                 ||||           CAT2                    |
|            value7                 ||||           CAT2                    |
|            value8                 ||||           CAT2                    |
|            value9                 ||||           CAT2                    |
|            value10                ||||           CAT2                    |
============================================================================

DFs[2] (Leftover/remainder) as SIZE!=5
============================================================================
|            COLUMN_Y               ||||          CATEGORY                 |
============================================================================
|            value11                 ||||           CAT3                   |
|            value12                 ||||           CAT3                   |
|            value13                 ||||           CAT3                   |
============================================================================
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please review [ask] and create a [mcve] that clearly demonstrates your problem.  Also make sure to show your own attempt!

Comment: Please add the code you have so far

Comment: Yes, you can do this by creating groupby in your dataframe.

Comment: Is that last record in the results supposed to be CAT4?  And, if you had CAT5 with six records, you want that CAT5 to be two groups one with 5 records and the sixth by itself?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, let's look at this exmaple.

Make test dataframe with your given dataframe and added a few records:

```
df = pd.concat([df,pd.DataFrame({'COLUMN_Y':['value'+str(i) for i in range(14,20)],
                                 'CATEGORY':['CAT5']*6})])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   COLUMN_Y CATEGORY
0    value1     CAT1
1    value2     CAT1
2    value3     CAT1
3    value4     CAT1
4    value5     CAT1
5    value6     CAT2
6    value7     CAT2
7    value8     CAT2
8    value9     CAT2
9   value10     CAT2
10  value11     CAT3
11  value12     CAT3
12  value13     CAT4
0   value14     CAT5
1   value15     CAT5
2   value16     CAT5
3   value17     CAT5
4   value18     CAT5
5   value19     CAT5
```

Let's create a custom groupby using `cumcount` and floor div by SIZE:

```
SIZE = 5
dfs = []
for n, g in df.groupby(['CATEGORY', df.groupby(['CATEGORY']).cumcount() // SIZE]):
    dfs.append(g)
```

Print output of list of dataframes split into groups:

```
for i, dfi in enumerate(dfs):
    print(f'df[{i}]:')
    print(dfi)
    print('\n')
```

Output:

```
df[0]:
  COLUMN_Y CATEGORY
0   value1     CAT1
1   value2     CAT1
2   value3     CAT1
3   value4     CAT1
4   value5     CAT1


df[1]:
  COLUMN_Y CATEGORY
5   value6     CAT2
6   value7     CAT2
7   value8     CAT2
8   value9     CAT2
9  value10     CAT2


df[2]:
   COLUMN_Y CATEGORY
10  value11     CAT3
11  value12     CAT3


df[3]:
   COLUMN_Y CATEGORY
12  value13     CAT4


df[4]:
  COLUMN_Y CATEGORY
0  value14     CAT5
1  value15     CAT5
2  value16     CAT5
3  value17     CAT5
4  value18     CAT5


df[5]:
  COLUMN_Y CATEGORY
5  value19     CAT5
```

Comment: @user1338194 Did this answer help you?  Would you mind accepting?